# Creating multiple divs within a single div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

If I have a parent div:

```
<div class="large-9 columns"></div>
```

and I want to create multiple child divs within the parent:

```
<div class="large-9 columns">
    <div>JSON data point 1</div>
    <div>JSON data point 2</div>
    <div>JSON data point 3</div>
</div>
```

How would I go about achieving this with my current implementation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", "form.message_form", function(event, xhr, settings) {
        var $messages = $(".messages");
        $('<div class="large-3 columns">').prepend($('<img>', { id: 'avatar', src: xhr.responseJSON.sender_avatar })).appendTo($messages);
        $('<div class="large-9 columns">')
            .append('<div>').html(xhr.responseJSON.content)
            .append('<div>').html('sent by ' + xhr.responseJSON.sender_name)
            .append('<div>').html('sent at ' + xhr.responseJSON.created_at)
            .appendTo($messages);
        $('#message_content').val('');
    });
});
```

At the moment only `xhr.responseJSON.created_at` is being rendered and not the other two data points?

Comment: Only need to modify few line.  Use .append('<div></div>')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you `append()` the new `div` elements, but you don't give them any content as the `append` function returns the element in the parent selector, not the new element. You then overwrite the `html()` of the new `.columns` div each time, so only the last value will be visible.

Try this:

```
var $container = $('<div />', { class: 'large-9 columns' }).appendTo($messages);
$('<div />', { html: xhr.responseJSON.content }).appendTo($container);
$('<div />', { html: 'sent by ' + xhr.responseJSON.sender_name }).appendTo($container);
$('<div />', { html: 'sent at ' + xhr.responseJSON.created_at }).appendTo($container);
```

Comment: thank you, great explanation of where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/8v15h3rt/) added multiple child divs, in the provide parent div

```
var childDivs = "<div>sasas</div>"
for(var i=0; i<childDivs.length; i++){
    $('.columns').append(childDivs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", "form.message_form", function(event, xhr, settings){
        var $messages = $(".messages");
        $('<div class="large-3 columns">').prepend( $('<img>', {id: 'avatar', src:xhr.responseJSON.sender_avatar}) ).appendTo($messages);
        $('<div class="large-9 columns">')
            .append('<div>' +xhr.responseJSON.content+'</div>')
            .append('<div> sent by '+ xhr.responseJSON.sender_name+'</div>')
            .append('<div> sent at ' + xhr.responseJSON.created_at+'</div></div>')
            .appendTo($messages);
        $('#message_content').val('');
    });
});
```

You are again and again overwriting the data written from `.append` by adding `.html` later which adds your `html` to `<div class="large-9 columns">` and not to the newly appended `html`